# How do I get the numbers for theorems, lemmas, examples, etc. before the type?

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am using the `article` document class with `amsthm`. I would like number the theorems/corollaries/examples, etc., consecutively as follows:

> 1.1 Theorem
>
> 1.2 Example
>
> 1.3 Example
>
> 1.4 Proposition

However, what my LaTeX renders is

> Theorem 1.1
>
> Example 1.2
>
> Example 1.3
>
> Proposition 1.4

How do I get a numbering as in the first?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

```
\swapnumbers
```

just before declaring your theorem-like structures. A little example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\swapnumbers
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{exam}[theo]{Example}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{theo}
test
\end{theo}
\begin{exam}
test
\end{exam}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. I was testing your first suggestion in the body rather than in the preamble. Now that you have given an example, all is clear and it has worked.