# Switch the position of theorem numbering

Tags: numbering

The usual behavior of latex is to write theorems as

Theorem 2.1.1

but I would like to have

2.1.1 Theorem

I think I remember seeing a command that allows you to do that but I don't remember it, any ideas ?

Comment: This question could use some more detail to ensure that you get an answer that pertains to the question. Are you defining the theorem inside of some environment? What environment? What package provides the environment?

Comment: This relies heavily on the package you may be using that provides you with theorem-writing capabilities (if any). Please present the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current behaviour.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Numbering theorem-like environments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44124/5764); [How do I get the numbers for theorems, lemmas, examples, etc. before the type?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17798/5764)

Comment: it `amsthm` is being used, the question cited by @Werner is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: Yes I am using amsthm and indeed the question linked answers mine. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Uese `\swapnumbers` in your preamble, before declaring your theorem-like structures.

Comment: As long there is no indication which package is used, there is no clear duplicate, in my point of view